# JScrollPane with transparent background and content

Tags: java, swing, transparency, paint

In my app, I show a popup dialog to show a large list of cards. I display them as images in many `JLabel` components in a `JPanel` subclass. I then put that object in a `JScrollPane` to allow for horizontal scrolling through the cards.

I want the unused space to be transparent with a dark background to show that what's behind it is disabled. I used `setBackground(new Color(50, 50, 50, 200))` to achieve the look I want, but the content behind it does not redraw, so I get artifacting.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Artifacting when scrolling]

How would I go about fixing this? How do I get the content behind it to redraw when I scroll?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking the window out of the equation for the momement.

The `JScrollPane` contains a `JViewport` which then contains you content.  So you need to set your content pane to transparent, the viewport to transparent and then the scroll pane to transparent.

You can achieve this by using `setOpaque(false)` on each of these containers.

This will ensure that the repaint manager will now paint through the background.

The next problem is, Swing doesn't actually support "semi-transparent" components (that is, either it's opaque or transparent).

You can implement this by overriding the `paintComponent` method of the main component (the one on the viewport is probably sufficient)

Comment: Good call on the `JViewport`. Didn't know that existed. I used a combination of both answers to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...might give you some relief during scrolling.
You likely also have a problem when the main frame is maximized
or restored.  You will need a listener for those events and a 
similar fix.

```
    jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(final AdjustmentEvent e) {
            sevenWondersframe.repaint();
        }
    });
    jScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(final AdjustmentEvent e) {
            sevenWondersframe.repaint();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I used a combination of both answers to fix it.