# Make background image show through panels on top

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, transparency

When I add panels and objects in panels, I want the image to be set as the background and show through the panels put on top of it. I read you can do this bet setting the `panel.setOpaque(false)` option, however this does not seem to work.

Here is my compiler directory and how it's setup (Using Intellij)...

[image]

Here is the background Image...

[image]

Here is the code...

BackgroundPanel class > http://www.camick.com/java/source/BackgroundPanel.java

```
/**
 * Created by James Page on 4/16/2017.
 */
package Main;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class TestGui extends JFrame {
    private final String[] guiCharSelDefault = {"---  Select Character ---"};
    private final String[] characters = {"charOne", "charTwo", "charThree", "charFour"};
    private final String[] GuiCharSel = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(guiCharSelDefault, characters);
    private final String[] weapon = {"Weapon"};
    private final String[][] allWeapons = {
            {
                    "weakWeaponOne", "strongWeaponOne", "shortWeaponOne", "longWeaponOne"
            },
            {
                    "weakWeaponTwo", "strongWeaponTwo", "shortWeaponTwo", "longWeaponTwo"
            },
            {
                    "weakWeaponThree", "strongWeaponThree", "shortWeaponThree", "longWeaponThree"
            },
            {
                    "weakWeaponFour", "strongWeaponFour", "shortWeaponFour", "longWeaponFour"
            }
    };
    private JComboBox charCombo = new JComboBox(GuiCharSel);
    private JComboBox weaponsCombo = new JComboBox(weapon);
    private BackgroundPanel backgroundFrame = createBackgroundFrame("../images/Background.png");
    private JPanel topFrame = createTopFrame();
    private JPanel centerFrame = createCenterFrame();

    //**************************************************************************************

    private static GridBagConstraints setGbc(int gridx, int gridy, int gridWidth, int gridHeight, int ipadx, int ipady, String anchorLocation, double weightx, double weighty, Insets insets){
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTHWEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTH")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTHEAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("WEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("EAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTHWEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTH")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTHEAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        } else {
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        }

        gbc.gridx = gridx; // column
        gbc.gridy = gridy; // row
        gbc.gridwidth = gridWidth; // number of columns
        gbc.gridheight = gridHeight; // number of rows
        gbc.ipadx = ipadx; // width of object
        gbc.ipady = ipady; // height of object
        gbc.weightx = weightx; // shifts rows to side of set anchor
        gbc.weighty = weighty; // shifts columns to side of set anchor
        gbc.insets = insets; // placement inside cell
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

        return gbc;
    }

    private Insets setInsets(int top, int left, int bottom, int right){
        Insets insets = new Insets(top,left,bottom,right);
        return insets;
    }

    //**************************************************************************************

    private BackgroundPanel createBackgroundFrame(String imgLocName){
        Image backgroundImg = null;
        try {
            backgroundImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(imgLocName));
            System.out.println("File: " + imgLocName.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot read file: " + e);
        }
        BackgroundPanel bgPanel = new BackgroundPanel(backgroundImg, BackgroundPanel.SCALED, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        return bgPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createTopFrame(){
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        Border raisedBevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        Color lineColor = new Color(224,224,224);
        Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(5, 5, 5, 5, lineColor);
        Border loweredBevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        Border compoundSetup = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedBevel, lineBorder);
        Border compoundFinal = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(compoundSetup, loweredBevel);
        TitledBorder topFrameTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(compoundFinal, "Character");
        topFrameTitle.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);

        JLabel lineSplitter = new JLabel();
        Border lineSplitterBoarder = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 5, new Color(224,224,224));
        lineSplitter.setBorder(lineSplitterBoarder);

        pnl.setBorder(topFrameTitle);
        pnl.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        pnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 60));

        charCombo.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String charName = ((JComboBox)(e.getSource())).getSelectedItem().toString();
                        if (charName.equals("charOne")){
                            weaponsCombo.removeAllItems();
                            weaponsCombo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(allWeapons[1]));
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        pnl.add(charCombo, setGbc(0,0, 1,1, 0,0, "WEST", 0, 0, setInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        pnl.add(lineSplitter, setGbc(1,0, 1,1, 0,0, "WEST", 0, 0, setInsets(0, 10, 0, 0)));
        pnl.add(weaponsCombo, setGbc(2,0, 1,1, 0,0, "WEST", 1, 1, setInsets(0, 10, 0, 0)));

        pnl.setOpaque(false);
        return pnl;
    }

    private JPanel createCenterFrame() {
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        Border raisedBevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        Color lineColor = new Color(224, 224, 224);
        Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(5, 5, 5, 5, lineColor);
        Border loweredBevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        Border compoundSetup = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedBevel, lineBorder);
        Border compoundFinal = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(compoundSetup, loweredBevel);
        TitledBorder topFrameTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(compoundFinal, "Stuff");
        topFrameTitle.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);

        pnl.setBorder(topFrameTitle);
        pnl.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        pnl.setOpaque(false);
        return pnl;
    }

    TestGui(){
        add(backgroundFrame);
        add(topFrame, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(centerFrame, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    //**************************************************************************************

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGui();
    }
}
```

I know the image background is being added to the gui, because if I comment out lines `//add(topFrame, BorderLayout.NORTH);` and `//add(centerFrame, BorderLayout.CENTER);` in the constructor, the image shows on the gui. Anyone have any idea how to make the background image show through these two panels?

Comment: Start by calling `setOpaque(false)` on your panels, ie `pnl.setOpaque(false)`. You'll find a lot of components are opaque by default (except `JLabel`, because it had to be different)

Comment: That's what I tried doing in lines 139 and 153 `pnl.setOpaque(false);`. It didn't seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the `backgroundFrame` with `centerFrame`

```
add(backgroundFrame);
add(topFrame, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(centerFrame, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This is feature of `BorderLayout`, where it can only support a single component at each of it's 5 available positions

Instead, what you want to do is either add the other panels to the `backgroundFrame` or set `backgroundFrame` as the frame's `contentPane`, for example

```
setContentPane(backgroundFrame);
add(topFrame, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(centerFrame, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

[image: Background]

Also, as a general suggestion, avoid using `setPreferredSize`, there are simply too many things that can make that go wrong

> Sorry to bother you again, it looks like it is not showing through the JScrollPane. Should I open this up as a new question?

The `JScrollPane` is a more complex component, which is made up of two components which are used to provide the functionality of scrolling

[image: JScrollPane]

You need to make the `JScrollPane` and it's `JViewport` transparent as well (as well as the view you wrap into it)

So, this is a modified version of your `createCenterFrame` method which creates a `JTextArea`, wraps into a `JScrollPane` and adds it to the `pnl`

```
private JPanel createCenterFrame() {
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    Border raisedBevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
    Color lineColor = new Color(224, 224, 224);
    Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(5, 5, 5, 5, lineColor);
    Border loweredBevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
    Border compoundSetup = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedBevel, lineBorder);
    Border compoundFinal = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(compoundSetup, loweredBevel);
    TitledBorder topFrameTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(compoundFinal, "Stuff");
    topFrameTitle.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);

    pnl.setBorder(topFrameTitle);
    pnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
    scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);

    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
    ta.setOpaque(false);
    ta.setText("This is an example of a transparent text area inside a transparent scroll pane, but you could just as easily wrap a transparent panel into it and get the same result");
    ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    ta.setLineWrap(true);

    scrollPane.setViewportView(ta);

    pnl.add(scrollPane);

    pnl.setOpaque(false);
    return pnl;
}
```

[image: Transparent scroll pane and text area]

Comment: YAY! Thanks again (MadProgrammer to the rescue!!!). The swing library has so many methods I have to learn, geez :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, it looks like it is not showing through the JScrollPane. Should I open this up as a new question?

Comment: @FiddleFreak That's more complicated, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422854/jscrollpane-with-transparent-background-and-content/15423000#15423000) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339103/transparent-jlist-in-jscrollpane-all-in-one-class/30339125#30339125) for more details

Comment: I think the best solution was to have the image set as it's own background in scrollpane `JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(backgroundFrame);`. Then add the panel inside of the scroll pane with the following lines `scrollPane.setOpaque(false);`, `scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);`, and `scrollPane.getViewport().setView(topFrame);`. I'm not sure if this was the best way to do it, but it's showing exactly how I want it.

Comment: If you wrap the `backgroundFrame` in the scrollpane, then you don't need to set it as transparent.  Call `setView` will replace the `backgroundFrame` with the `topFrame` ... so not really working as you might expect.  The solution will depend on what you hope to achieve

Comment: [Here's another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677850/add-background-image-in-jtable/13678077#13678077), which either makes the component responsible for managing the background, which allows it to scroll, or the `JViewport` to make it sticky, but in you case, just make the `JScrollPane` (and `viewport`) transparent and adding it to the current container will do the same thing

Comment: Yeah, I think removing the extra panel and just transferring all the settings to the scroll pane is the better call.

Comment: Actually nevermind, I can't use GridBagLayout with JScrollPane. So I'll just stick with JPanel inside the JScrollPane.